# WP 8.1 Runtime code to make phone call, send SMS & send Email (not the Silverlight 8.1)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, sms, phone-call

I'm writing an app which will make a phone call, send sms or email just like the People app in wp 8.1 .
So far I've found a link form msdn which said "Applies to: Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1".
So here the code:[from this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

private void TextBlock_Tapped_Call(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
    phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "2065550123";
    phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Gage";

    phoneCallTask.Show();
}
```

But I got an error:

The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Edit: Sorry for a duplicate question, same here: [Make a phone call in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555640/make-a-phone-call-in-windows-phone-8-1) 
Answer by @Chris Shao, he also updated code to send SMS and Email.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Microsoft.Phone.dll`?

Comment: much obliged for your reply, I don't really get it but i've open reference manager, tab Windows phone 8.1. It said The Windows Phone 8.1 SDK is already referenced . Does I do it right? Or how to reference it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to use `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks`, you must create **Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1** project. And if your project is **Windows Phone 8.1**,

you can use this code to phone call:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI("phone number", "display name");
```

and use this to send sms:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage msg = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage();
msg.Body = "This is body of demo message.";
msg.Recipients.Add("10086");
msg.Recipients.Add("10010");
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(msg);
```

and use this to send mail:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage mail = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
mail.Subject = "This is Subject";
mail.Body = "This is body of demo mail";
mail.To.Add(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient("shaom_wp@hotmail.com", "shaomeng"));
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);
```

Comment: much obliged @Chris what about sms task in windows phone 8.1 (not the silverlight) Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Truong N, I've updated my answer.Please read and vote up the answer.Thx!

Comment: tks alot @Chris, what about send email? I guess it also in Windows.ApplicationModel.Email ... smt?

Comment: Yes, send email is in Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.

Comment: so how to write the code about send email ? I have googled and written myself but it no work. @Chris help me, I'm sure will upvote the comment

Comment: Hi, I've update my answer.send mail is Added. Please read it.

Comment: much obliged ! Tks so much @Chris

Comment: Hi @Chris , I wonder when I use your Email code, it said:
Can't share. There are no apps to share with.
Detail here in this [image](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/5999/4ke5.png).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can debug it on your Device, because there are email account on Emulator.

Comment: ahh, got it. Tks alot. :))