# Is it possible to send SMS from Windows 8.1 Store app not windows phone app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I am developing a **Windows 8.1 store app** . In my app I want to send **SMS** with some text to a phone number . **This is a desktop app not a phone app**.

Is it possible?
If possible can you tell me one example how to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP 8.1 Runtime code to make phone call, send SMS & send Email (not the Silverlight 8.1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797559/wp-8-1-runtime-code-to-make-phone-call-send-sms-send-email-not-the-silverlig)

Comment: hey that link for windows phone app . How is it possible to send from desktop app. Why you duplicated my question ? Can you please tell me one reason why you down voted?

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression this was on mobile because you wanted to send SMS. What kind of device do you have on your desktop that allows you to send SMS?

Comment: I don't have any device . I just want to send sms from my app? Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot send SMS without a connection to the mobile network.

Comment: if you don't mind one suggestion first read question carefully and then decide to up vote or down vote .....

Comment: okay but we can send sms from websites example [link](http://www.shoppirate.in/view/amazon) there  below the button steal the deal you will find sms , how to works with out network?

Comment: Companies like such tend to use external services provided by other xompanies to send their messages.

Comment: okay fine thanks for your help and down vote........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send SMS from anywhere but you'll have to buy the service from a text provider. When you send a sms from a phone you do this using the mobile connection available on the phone, when you want to do this from a device that isn't on a mobile network with a mobile plan including text you need to purchase this from a web service provider that will submit the text you send to them to the mobile network for a fee.

Just Google up "text message web service" or "SMS web service" and you'll find plenty that go from cheap to expensive, typically sold in bulk. Price varies a lot depending on your target country.