# How to send SMS programatically in Windows Phone 8.1(C#)

Tags: c#, sms, windows-phone-8.1

I want to send SMS programatically for that i am using below code but seems that it dontwork in 8.1

```
   SmsComposeTask SMSCompose = new SmsComposeTask();
   SMSCompose.To = "<Number to which the SMS needs to be sent";
   SMSCompose.Body = "Message that needs to be sent";
   SMSCompose.Show();
```

Is there any othey way to achive it?

Comment: What doesn't work? The docs for `SmsComposeTask` indicate it works on WP 8.1.

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any exception/error? Are you targeting *Silverlight* or *RunTIme*? Have you tried like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23797884/2681948)?

Comment: i am developing an universal application, visual studio dosent found any reference to it

Comment: i think this is workin
Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage msg = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage();
msg.Body = "This is body of demo message.";
msg.Recipients.Add("10086");
msg.Recipients.Add("10010");
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(msg);

Answer (score 2):

```
    public async static Task SendMessage (string phoneNumber)
    {
        ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage();
        msg.MessageKind = Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageKind.Standard;
        msg.Body = "...";
        msg.Recipients.Add(phoneNumber);
        ChatMessageStore cms = await ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();
        cms.SendMessageAsync(msg);
    }
```

This should send the message on Windows Phone 8.1. You may want to check if cms is not null, just in case...

Comment: When I try this on a Lumia 550 running Windows 10 I get a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` at the `SendMessageAsync` call. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Figured it out. The app needed the restricted capability `cellularMessaging` as seen in the [docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt270968.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You should do some searching before make a new thread. Your question is already a part in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797559/wp-8-1-runtime-code-to-make-phone-call-send-sms-send-email-not-the-silverlig). The universal app is also called windows runtime, so same solution in [that threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797559/wp-8-1-runtime-code-to-make-phone-call-send-sms-send-email-not-the-silverlig) if you want to send message or event call or send email.
You can use this for send message:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage msg = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage();
msg.Body = "This is body of demo message.";
msg.Recipients.Add("10086");
msg.Recipients.Add("10010");
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(msg);
```

Enjoy coding!

P/s: update from @Sinaesthetic , this just compose the message, it'll not send it, all user has to do is to hit the send button :)

Comment: This only composes the text message, but does not send it.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic no way you could do that on windows phone. Simp 'cause the OS not allow that.

Comment: I realize that. But it would have been useful to know in these posts while I was still figuring that out. The question was asking how to send, it probably would have been better to lead answers with "you can't actually send anything, only compose), so I wanted to make a note of it. I didn't down-vote or anything :)

Comment: Please clarify "no way you could do that on windows phone". 
Do you mean it is impossible? How are other Apps doing this then if it's not possible?

Comment: If I remember right, back in those day, API was kinda strict, can you please name an app, and of couse please correct if I wrong. Tks.