# Windows Phone 8.1: Can we capture event for Answer and End Call

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

When I make a call, someone will click the "Answer" button to answer my call => Can we capture the action "click the Answer button" from my phone?
Thanks!

Comment: You mean triggering something, when the person you called answer the call?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case, there's no such way you could do that. Where as you could only make calls to a person from your contacts list.

Reference: [WP 8.1 Runtime code to make phone call, send SMS & send Email (not the Silverlight 8.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797559/)

You could go through this article from [msdn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797559/wp-8-1-runtime-code-to-make-phone-call-send-sms-send-email-not-the-silverlig) for more.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your idea, but I would like to explain more my case:
-When I call to anyone, they answer my call, I want to capture/get a notification/event/action so that I know that my phone is transferring data. After that I can count the time or call other events.
Thanks

Comment: @dslkhodau What do you mean by transferring data, after that person answers the call?

Comment: It is the voice (mine & answerer's)

Comment: Capture notification of what, as of you mentioned in the comment?

Comment: Notification or event or anything that I can capture after that I will trigger my other event

Comment: As i could get what you're asking is to trigger something when the person answer's your call, which is impossible.