# Windows Phone - functionality questions ( make a call from app, persistent connection etc )

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

The company I work for is considering to build an application for Windows Phone. Well, actually we plan to build an universal app ( for phone, tablet and PC ).

There are some requirements ( especially for Phone version ), so I would like to clarify few things before allocating resources & hiring people.

I would be very grateful, if some Windows expert goes through these requirements and confirm that this is possible.

So:
1) We need to launch a call within the application.
I've found this solution:
[Make a phone call in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555640/make-a-phone-call-in-windows-phone-8-1)
The question: is it possible to launch a call without a prompt? As far as I understand this solution prompts a question to user, if he wants to call or not. Our flow and design is made in a way, that this prompt will be redundant ( of course, we launch a call on user's behalf ).

2) We need to maintain internet persistent connection and be able to react if some message comes using this persistent connection. I've checked PubNub and it seems that everything is OK and PubNub provides SDK for Windows Phone.
Important: this is not VoIP application, so it might get complicated if Microsoft has some policies that persistent connection might be used only by VoIP application ( Apple has these policies ).
Important thing: Persistent connection should stay connected, if application goes background, so there should be no "cut off".

3) We should be able to present some notification ( with sound alarm ) to user and launch the app if he "accepts" the notification. Basically, we should be able to send some message to the device using PubNub or even Microsoft WNS service for pushes and present the notification on the device. Like "Local Notification" in iOS.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,
Maksim

Answer (score 0):

1)Unfortunately on Windows Phone you can't start a call without the system prompt.. It's for security..

2)I can't help you here..

3)Of course you can send notification to a device. This notifications are called toast notification.
A notification's custom sound can't be setted within the app, you have to load the sound on a server or let the user decide (he can change the sound in the system settings). If you don't need a custom sound.. no problem, it'll be used the default ones and you don't have to worry about anything.
I use Parse.com to send push notifications or you can even run a sheduled task every 30 mins on the user's phone(maybe is not appropriate for your application).
In the notification you can also set the property navigationUri to open the app on a defined page.
Unfortunately you can't still customize the notification aspect(you'll be able to do it in Windows 10) and you can see the default aspect here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/ToastNotification/PushNotification.png